# NoneType object has no attribute find_all error using beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to read the following:

[image]

My goal is to read every job title from this page - `https://www.cvbankas.lt/?miestas=Vilnius&padalinys%5B%5D=&keyw=python`

What I've tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.cvbankas.lt/?miestas=Vilnius&padalinys%5B%5D=&keyw=python'
page = requests.get(URL).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='ResultsContainer')
 
# Look for Python jobs
python_jobs = results.find_all("div", string=lambda t: "python" in t.lower())

for p_job in python_jobs:
    link = p_job.find("h3")["href"]
    print(p_job.text.strip())
    print(f"Apply here: {link}\n")
```

But I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

How can I read all the titles?

Comment: Are you sure that there is an element with id 'ResultsContainer' there?

Comment: when i open devtools on the URL you've specified , i dont even find the id `ResultsContainer`  - which is in your code

Comment: It is probably should be 'main_container' id.

Comment: Also I'm not sure that `div` tag name is a right choice at `results.find_all("div", string=lambda t: "python" in t.lower())`. A right choice is probably `article`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is, there isn't any tag with `id="ResultsContainer"`. You can search all `<h3>` tags with text Python and then find parent `<a>` tag for an url:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = 'https://www.cvbankas.lt/?miestas=Vilnius&padalinys%5B%5D=&keyw=python'
page = requests.get(URL).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('h3', text=lambda t: 'python' in t.lower())
for r in results:
    print(r.text)
    print(r.find_parent('a')['href'])
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Senior Python Developer
https://www.cvbankas.lt/senior-python-developer-vilniuje/1-6719819
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Full Stack Engineer (React + Python)
https://www.cvbankas.lt/full-stack-engineer-react-python-vilniuje/1-6665723
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Python programuotojas (Mid-Senior)
https://www.cvbankas.lt/python-programuotojas-mid-senior-vilniuje/1-6693547
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Python Developer
https://www.cvbankas.lt/python-developer-vilniuje/1-6604883
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is there is no element has a id `"ResultsContainer"`.

But refer to the struct of the page, You could use `css selector` to get all the information directly:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.cvbankas.lt/?miestas=Vilnius&padalinys%5B%5D=&keyw=python'
page = requests.get(URL).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
results = soup.select("div.list_cell > .list_h3")
for i in results:
    print(i.text)
```

Result:

```
Data Engineer
Data Analyst
VYRESNYSIS INŽINIERIUS STRATEGIJOS IR TYRIMŲ SKYRIUJE
Senior Python Developer
Full Stack Engineer (React + Python)
DevOps Engineer
Linux Systems Automation Engineer
Big Data Developer
Big Data Devops Engineer
Python programuotojas (Mid-Senior)
DATA SCIENTIST
DEVOPS INŽINIERIAUS (e-commerce platformos produktų optimizavimas užsienio rinkoms)
LINUX Sistemų administratorius (-ė)
QA engineer
Blockchain Developer
Backend Software Engineer
FW/HW Quality Assurance Engineer
Software developer in Test
Python Developer
Senior Backend Engineer
```

Answer (score 0):

This method: `soup.find(id='ResultsContainer')` found no element matching the criteria, and therefore returned `None`.

In this line: `python_jobs = results.find_all("div", string=lambda t: "python" in t.lower())`, the value of `results` is `None`.

`None.find_all` does not exist. (`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`)

Comment: Please use the comment section for suggestions if you do not  provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout my codes:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://www.cvbankas.lt/?miestas=Vilnius&padalinys%5B%5D=&keyw=python'
page = requests.get(URL).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
h3_tags = soup.findAll("h3", {"class": "list_h3"})
for x in h3_tags:
    if "Python" in x.text:
        print(x.text)
        print(x.find_parent('a')['href'])
        print()
```

And The output are:

```
Senior Python Developer
https://www.cvbankas.lt/senior-python-developer-vilniuje/1-6719819

Full Stack Engineer (React + Python)
https://www.cvbankas.lt/full-stack-engineer-react-python-vilniuje/1-6665723

Python programuotojas (Mid-Senior)
https://www.cvbankas.lt/python-programuotojas-mid-senior-vilniuje/1-6693547

Python Developer
https://www.cvbankas.lt/python-developer-vilniuje/1-6604883
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace your code with below code:

```
import requests
from lxml import etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.cvbankas.lt/?miestas=Vilnius&padalinys%5B%5D=&keyw=python'
page = requests.get(URL).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))
elements = dom.xpath('//h3[@class="list_h3"]')
for element in elements:
  print(element.text)
```